# При использовании letter-spacing не получается выровнять текст по центру

Tags: html, css

Есть **logo** с большим `font-size`. Необходимо сделать так же большие отступы между букв. Проблема в том, что текст почему-то смещается влево, а не равномерно распределяя отступы, оставаясь по центру. Прошу помочь, заранее спасибо.

```css
header {
  background-color: red;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1170px;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.intro {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 700px;
  font-size: 450px;
  letter-spacing: 350px;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<header>
  TEXT
</header>
<main>
  <div class="container">
    <div class=intro>
      ABC
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: оберните каждую букву и задайте необходимо расположение - https://jsfiddle.net/gnq04L7j/

Comment: А без оберток не выйдет? Сам хотел так сделать, но - допустим из админки уже не отредактируешь и не введешь больше букв для лого(WorldPress к примеру?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> А без оберток не выйдет? Сам хотел так сделать, но - допустим из админки уже не отредактируешь и не введешь больше букв для лого(WorldPress к примеру?).

Тупой вариант, но почему бы и нет?

```js
$('.title').each(function(){
  let len = $(this).text().length,
      textArr = $(this).text().split('');
  $(this)
    .css('--size-text', (100/len)+'vw')
    .html(`<div>${textArr.join('</div><div>')}</div>`);
});
```

```css
.title {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-size: var(--size-text, inherit);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="title">ABC</div>
<div class="title">STACKOVERFLOW</div>
```